# Rails console and postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out which database i'm using in the rails console, i understand it says `Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)`, so i'm presuming its whatever database i listed in development in gemfile but i'm not so sure, is there a way of checking this inside the console?, or is it better to just use the psql command line with raw sql, because from what i see, active record queries don't work with the pg command line.

Active record in postgres console.

```
psql (9.4.0, server 9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.

spencerlong=# User.all
spencerlong-#
```

Better yet, a console with postgres AND Active_record capabilities.

Comment: `active record queries don't work with the pg command line` yeah, pgsql is no ruby

Comment: granted yes, so do you know of a way to run postgres database in rails console, (for querying active record) or is it whatever you listed in gemfile under given environment., thats what you'll use.

Answer (score 1):

Write a below command in `rails console` to get database name

```
Rails.configuration.database_configuration["development"]["database"]
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Rails::Configuration:Module is what i get from that.

Comment: I just update my post, please see, I have rails 4.0 version, it works for me